# Width of ticks in multiplot in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Could you help me with the following script please? How to set the width of ticks in this multiplot for plotting 6 subplots?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import array
import matplotlib as mpl

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(sharex=True)
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9))

fig1 = plt.subplot(231)
plt.plot(x, y**2)
fig1.set_xlim(0e-13,2e-13)
fig1.set_ylim(-1.15e-14,0.01e-14)
fig2=plt.subplot(232)
plt.plot(x, y**2)
fig2.set_xlim(0e-13,2e-13)
fig2.set_ylim(-7.3e-15,7.3e-15)
fig3=plt.subplot(233)
plt.plot(x, y**2)
fig3.set_ylim(0e-13,1.2e-13)
fig3.set_xlim(0e-13,2e-13)
fig4=plt.subplot(234)
plt.plot(x, y**2)
fig4.set_xlim(-1.15e-14,0.01e-14)
fig4.set_ylim(-7.3e-15,7.3e-15)
fig5=plt.subplot(235)
plt.plot(x, y**2)
fig5.set_xlim(-7.3e-15,7.3e-15)
fig5.set_ylim(0e-13,1.2e-13)
plt.tight_layout(pad=0.4, w_pad=0.5, h_pad=1.0)
fig6=plt.subplot(236)
plt.plot(x, y**2)
fig6.set_xlim(-1.5e-14,0e-14)
fig6.set_ylim(0e-13,1.2e-13)
plt.show()
```

I tried:

```
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(width=2)
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(width=2)
```

and

```
for figures in [fig1, fig2, fig3, fig4, fig5, fig6]:
    ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(width=2)
    ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(width=2)
```

but nothing has changed and the width of ticks stayed the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the following

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(sharex=True)
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9))
```

creates two figures, which I guess you do not want.

Second, when you execute `fig1 = plt.subplot(231)`, you do not create a Figure object but rather an Axes one. This call is redundant as it can be handled directly with `plt.subplots()`.

Third, `ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(width=2)` has no effect in the figure you are interested in because ax refers to the axis created by `fig, ax = plt.subplots(sharex=True)` and not to any axis in the current figure you are drawing in, which was created by `plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9))`.

Have a look below for a cleaner version.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

fig, axarr = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3)
for ax in axarr.flatten():
    ax.plot(x, y ** 2)
    ax.tick_params(width=2)
fig.tight_layout(pad=0.4, w_pad=0.5, h_pad=1.0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that my script is not a nice script, but is it possible to write `ax.tick_params(width=2)` in individual fig1 part, fig2 part...?

Comment: Well, if you do not want to use a loop logic, then you will have to manually write `figX.tick_params(width=2)` for X going from 1 to 6 in your case. I know the loop looks very compact and it is not obvious how to deal with each graph separately. However, if instead of `for ax in axarr.flatten():`, we write `for i, ax in enumerate(axarr.flatten()):`, then you have an index i that you can use to identify your current axis. For example, if statements become possible `if i == 2: ax.set_xlim((0, 10))`.

Comment: One more question please? How to hide labels to display only ticks? I tried:
`labels = [item.get_text() for item in ax.get_xticklabels()]`  
`empty_string_labels = ['']*len(labels)`  
`fig1.set_xticklabels(empty_string_labels)`

Comment: If you are using `subplots` and that all your subplots have the same X and/or Y axis, adding `sharex=True` and/or `sharey=True` to subplots will do the trick. Apart from this, the regular way is with `tick_params`, passing for example `labelbottom=False`. Have a look [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. I have labels 1, 2, ... x10 to 2. When I use `labelbottom=False` x 10 to 2 stay there. Is there a specific name for this?